# Convex mirror cut in half

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, visible-light

if I cut the convex mirror in half then how will  the image be formed??
suppose I have a convex mirror and I cut it in half then how will the focal length of the mirror change?

Answer (score 2):

Focal length will remain unaffected as it depends only on radius of curvature which is constant in this case.
What will change is the intensity of the image formed because only half the light is getting reflected as compared to full mirror.

Answer (score 1):

the focal length will be unchanged but only the clarity of the image will be diminished since only a part of the light is being reflected